# get the value from another class

Tags: java, return

Main.java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String username ="";
    String password = "";
    Class_b b = new Class_b();
    b.login("username","password");
 }
```

Class_b.java

```
public String login(String user, String pass) {
      String username = "admin";
      String password = "password";
      return username+" "+password;
}
```

I want to get the `username` and `password` values from `Class_b` and store it into the string variables `username` and `password` in Main.java.

Comment: You are apparently passing the username and password into the login function FROM main, why would you need to return it back to main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return a custom java type, or just an array of `String`<sup>**1**</sup>. Something like

Class_b.java

```
public String[] login(String user, String pass) {
      String username = "admin";
      String password = "password";
      return new String[] { username, password };
}
```

and then you might invoke it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String username ="";
    String password = "";
    Class_b b = new Class_b();
    String[] arr = b.login(username,password);
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        username = arr[0];
        password = arr[1];
    }
    System.out.println("username=" + username + ", password=" + password);
}
```

<sup>**1**<sub>It's also not clear why you're passing the `String`(s) to your method, you ignore them and return new values.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use spilt() method
For e.g.

```
String temp = b.login("username","password");
String login[] = temp.split("\\s+");
/*spilts username & password separated by space*/
System.out.print(login[0]); //prints username
System.out.println(login[1]); //prints password
```

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Create class Class_b:

```
public class Class_b {

private String username;

private String password;

public Class_b() {
    this.username = "admin";
    this.password = "password";
}

/**
 * @return the username
 */
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

/**
 * @param username
 *            the username to set
 */
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

/**
 * @param password
 *            the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

Step2: In Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class_b class_b = new Class_b();
    username = class_b.getUsername();
    password = class_b.getUsername();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Good Idea to use getter and setter. it help me to understand what the getters and setters does